# Jquery/Javascript Ajax calls and updating textbox with result data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is probably ugly, but it's almost doing what I want. I am making a few ajax calls and updating a text input box with some information. I have a couple questions about this.

```
function runTasks(){
    // update params before running
    var userid=  $('#id').val().toUpperCase()
    var Parlist_BEGDATE = $('#start_date').val()
    var Parlist_ENDDATE = $('#end_date').val()
        
        for(b=0; b < clientHash.length; b++){
            for(x=0; x < $('#selected_clients > option').length; x++){
                if(clientHash[b].client === $('#selected_clients > option')[x].innerText){      
                    runTaskID = clientHash[b].taskId
                    runTaskClient = clientHash[b].client
                    runTaskURL = taskListURL + "/" + runTaskID + "/start"; 
                        
                        $.ajax({
                            url: tokenURL,
                            method: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            data: {
                                grant_type: 'refresh_token',
                                refresh_token: login_obj.refresh_token
                            },
                            headers: {
                                'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                Accept:'application/json'
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                obj = data    // result
                                login_obj = obj
                            }
                        })
                        // done getting the authorization token.

                        taskUpdateURL = taskListURL + "/" + runTaskID
                        
                        // Let's get the task so we can start it.
                        $.ajax({
                            url: taskUpdateURL,
                            method: 'GET',
                            async: false,
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token,
                                'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                Accept:'application/json'
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                taskname_obj3 = data    // result
                            }
                        })
                

                        var payload = new Object();
                        payload = {
                                id: $('#id').val().toUpperCase(),
                                Parlist_BEGDATE: $('#start_date').val(),
                                Parlist_ENDDATE: $('#end_date').val()
                        };
        
            
                        // Let's run the task. 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: runTaskURL,
                            method: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                taskname_obj2 = data    // result
                            }
                        })          

                    //Timeout to make things smoother
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        console.log("appending to console log - " + runTaskClient);
                        $('#resultDivText').append('<b><font color="#684CA1">' + runTaskClient + "</font></b> started: " + taskname_obj2.nominalStart + "<br>"); 
                    }, 5000);                       
                                    
                }
            }
        }



}
```

When I run this, everything works except my update to the '#resultDivText' element. The `runTaskClient` variable is not getting updated it looks like. It looks like the `runTaskID` variable is though, because my function is making calls to the correct URLs for every item in my loop. When my results are `.append` though it's only appending the last value it finds from the `#selected_clients` select element.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does my `runTaskID` appear to be updating fine, but my `runTaskClient` is only holding the last value from the select element?

One other strange behavior is the `setTimeout`. When the for loops run, it looks like its just doing the one single timeout when I test two values. It seems to do one timeout then it appends both lines at once with the last value found in the select box. I need it to pause for each item while it updates my the text inputbox.

My best guess is that the problem is my `async: false` statements. I imagine they should be true and I should be putting results into some kind of array and using a different function to enumarate that? Thoughts?

------**UPDATE**-----
If I remove the setTimeout and just let things happen, then I see the correct output. If I add the setTimeout back in, I am seeing the last value from the select box over and over for however many items are in the for loop.

I want the for loop to pause for 3 to 4 seconds on each iteration, and i want the data to be correct.

Comment: Make sure you declare all your variables as local variables with `let` or `const`. You'll run into lots of problems using global variables in asynchronous code.

Comment: I moved `runTaskID`, `runTaskClient`, `runTaskURL` to be local instead of global. The behavior in question remains the same unfortunately.

Comment: I said ALL the variables. Some of them may not matter, but you should always declare variables unless you need them to be global.